# Changing Column type using astype does not work - Goal make a Join

Tags: python, pandas

I need to make a join into tables, and for that, I need to make a column type change but Is not changing. This is my code, the dataset is open source.

```
import pandas as pd
import json
from urllib.request import urlopen

#Get Data
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sthemonica/alura-voz/main/Dados/Telco-Customer-Churn.json'
response = urlopen(url)
strfile = response.read().decode('utf-8', 'replace')
jsonfile = json.loads(strfile)
dft = pd.json_normalize(data=jsonfile)

# My Problem
print('Before', dft['Churn'].dtypes)
dft = dft.astype({'Churn': str})
print('After', dft['Churn'].dtypes)
```

Result:

```
Before object
After object
```

note, I also try:

```
dft = dft.astype({'Churn': "str"})
dft.astype({'Churn': "str"})
dft.astype({'Churn': str})
```

What I'm doing wrong? This is the join a what to do:

```
dtemp = [[0, 'No'],
     [1, 'Yes']]
columns_names = ['Id', 'Churn']
df_FromTo = pd.DataFrame(data=dtemp, columns=columns_names)
dft = dft.join(df_FromTo, on='Churn', rsuffix="_del")
```

Result:

```
ValueError: You are trying to merge on object and int64 columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 dft = dft.merge(df_FromTo, on='Churn')
```

Answer (score 0):

See [`pandas.DataFrame.join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) `on` argument explanation

> Column or index level name(s) in the `caller` to join on the index in `other`, otherwise joins index-on-index.

When you do `dft.join(df_FromTo, on='Churn', rsuffix="_del")`, `caller` is `dft`, `other` is `df_FromTo`, you are joining with `dft['Churn']` with `df_FromTo.index`

You can fix with

```py
dft = dft.join(df_FromTo.set_index('Churn'), on='Churn', rsuffix="_del")
```

Comment: Tks, but I can't set_index to another column. I will not be able to keep track of all changes (this will be called in a loop). Ian's solution fits better in my case.